# Cant display values in Django templates

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django, I am trying to display a single book in a template(show.html) like

```
 <h1 class="text-center text-4xl py-5">{{book.title}}</h1>
    <img src="{{ book.thumbnailUrl }}" alt="" class="w-56">
    <p>{{book.shortDescription}}</p>
    <p>{{book.longDescription}}</p>
```

The view rendering the template is (trying to render a single book from JSON file by id)

```
def show(request, id):
    with open('bookstore/books.json') as file:
        book_dict = json.load(file)['books']

    book = [book for book in book_dict if book['id'] == id]
    context = {'book': book}

    return render(request, 'books/show.html', context)
```

When debugging by printing {{ book }} in show.html it results in a list with a dictionary of a book

```
[{'id': 1, 'title': 'Unlocking Android', 'isbn': '1933988673', 'pageCount': 416, 'publishedDate': {'$date': '2009-04-01T00:00:00.000-0700'},...}]
```

Hence I think that's the problem when I try to access the title using dict syntax like({{ book. title}} )

But I can't seem to find a workaround.

Comment: Your `book` is a list.  It happens to be a list with 1 element, but it's still a list.  So, just do `context = { 'book': book[0] }`.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you don't need a list comprehension at all,

```
def show(request, id):
    with open('bookstore/books.json') as file:
        book_dict = json.load(file)['books']
    
    book = None
    for book in book_dict:
        if book['id'] == id:
            break
            
    context = {'book': book}

    return render(request, 'books/show.html', context)
```